# use tts demo but prompt file occupation

Tags: text-to-speech, coqui

https://docs.coqui.ai/en/latest/tutorial_for_nervous_beginners.html

TTS demo in winodw

Excute

```
set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 & python train.py
```

this is error message

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 125, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 236, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
    main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 268, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\Desktop\1\tts.py", line 84, in <module>
    trainer.fit()
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\trainer.py", line 1860, in fit
    remove_experiment_folder(self.output_path)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\trainer\generic_utils.py", line 77, in remove_experiment_folder
    fs.rm(experiment_path, recursive=True)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\fsspec\implementations\local.py", line 172, in rm
    shutil.rmtree(p)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 749, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 627, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\dzj05\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 625, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] 另一个程序正在使用此文件，进程无法访问。: 'C:/Users/dzj05/Desktop/1/run-February-26-2024_10+28PM-0000000\\trainer_0_log.txt'
```

but i don't use C:/Users/dzj05/Desktop/1/run-February-26-2024_10+28PM-0000000\trainer_0_log.txt

create a folder  is also like this